# Use reactive form with angular 2 dropdown multiselect

Tags: angular, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm trying to use the [angular 2 dropdown multiselect library](https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect) with reactive forms.

I have followed the tutorial for reactive model and have this:

```
this.myOptions = [
    { id: 1, name: 'English' },
    { id: 2, name: 'French' },
];

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    langs:[1, 2]
});
```

And in my html (in pug):

```
ss-multiselect-dropdown([options]='myOptions', formControlName='langs')
```

And get the following error: `TypeError: this.validator is not a function`

So I've tried:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    langs:this.formBuilder.array([1, 2])
});
```

And get the following error: `TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function`

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug?

You can see a [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/MzukQC8M7l0xUKBC0wL5?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand from your Question that, You want to select both values on init.

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  optionsModel: [[1,2]] // Default model
});
```

Both values will be selected default

Updated Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/tvLYUzgsCkXODXX6qKrN?p=preview